# Enabling kerberos on Azure hdinsight cluster

Tags: azure, kerberos, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I have deployed standard(without ESP) Azure HDInsight cluster version 3.6. I need to enable Kerberos authentication for this hdinsight cluster. But I could not see Kerberos option in Ambari Admin. My question is
1. In order to enable kerberos, the hdinsight cluster must be created with enterprise security package enabled?
2. Is it possible to enable esp after creating hdinsight cluster?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In order to enable kerberos, the hdinsight cluster must be created with enterprise security package enabled?

Yes, in order to enable kerberos you need to create HDInsight cluster with ESP enabled.

> 2. Is it possible to enable esp after creating hdinsight cluster?

No, it is not possible to enable ESP after creating HDInsight cluster.

**Note:** HDInsight cluster nodes with Enterprise Security Package (ESP) are joined to a domain that's managed by Azure AD DS. Kerberos security is configured for the Hadoop components on the cluster.

Make sure you have configured a HDInsight cluster with Enterprise Security Package by using Azure Active Directory Domain Services.

While creating a cluster => Select Custom create and Enable Enterprise Security Package.

[image]

For more details refer “[Configured a HDInsight cluster with Enterprise Security Package by using Azure Active Directory Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/domain-joined/apache-domain-joined-configure-using-azure-adds)”.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response. How about Hive Metastore settings? Do we need to specify during the creation of HDInsight cluster itself? I don't see option of linking external hive metastore(Azure SQL database) with HDInsight cluster after creating it in Azure portal.

Thanks

[Hive metastore specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNSB1.png)

Comment: You cannot link external metastore after creating cluster. Even for Hive Metastore, you need to link it while creating the cluster.